# Delphi: TreeView elements vs. Form position changing

Tags: delphi, count, treeview, element, handle

We have found something is seems to be a bug(?), and cause bug in our code.

Delphi XE3, Win32. Two forms, the main have button:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    with TForm1.Create(Application) do
    begin
        ShowModal;
        Release;
    end;
end;
```

The Form1 is doing this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
    i, j: integer;
    mn: TTreeNode;
begin
    for i := 1 to 10 do
    begin
        mn := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, 'M' + IntToStr(i));
        for j := 1 to 10 do
        begin
            TreeView1.Items.AddChild(mn, 'C' + IntToStr(j));

        end;
    end;
    Position := poDesigned;
    beep;
    Caption := IntToStr(TreeView1.Items.Count);
end;
```

After this I get 0 elements in caption.

But when I have a button in that form with this code...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Caption := IntToStr(TreeView1.Items.Count);
end;
```

...

Then I can see the good number (110 elements).

If I write TreeView1.Handleneeded after Position changing, the count is also good.

The problem is based on RecreateWnd, which calls DestroyHandles.
But they will be repaired only in Show (in the Activate event I can see good result too).

TreeView is a special control, because the tree elements are children, and the count is calculated by on them, no matter it have real sub-object list.

The main problem that ReCreateWnd called often by another methods to, so it can cause problems in another sections too, and I cannot put HandleNeeded before all .Count calculation.

(We have special base form that correct the Position to poDesigned if it was poScreenCenter to it can be positionable later. This happens after FormCreate call, in an inner method. We found this problem only with these kind of forms, but later we could reproduce it in a simple code too)

So the question is - what is the global solution to this problem?

(Did you experience this in XE5 too?)

Thank you for all help, info, doc.

Comment: What are these other scenarios where `RecreateWnd` is called?

Comment: My coll. said he found these: CMCtlD3Changed
CMSysColorChange
BORDERSTYLE
SetAxBorderStyle
SetBorderIcons
Dock
SetPosition
SetPopupMode
set_PopupParent
RecreateAsPopup
ShowModal
SetMainFormOnTaskBar

Comment: No. I mean what are the other scenarios where `RecreateWnd` is called with the consequence of your program not working. In normal use, when you code in response to user events, you should not have a problem with the handle not being allocated.

Comment: So. It's an old application that ported, and full of autocreate forms.
More form uses the "Article form" for example, which holds the "Article Tree". This generated in FormCreate, populated from DataBase.
Another forms uses this, but they get 0 as ArticleForm.TreeView.Count.
The treeviews commonly used everywhere - and we experienced these problems by user's report... Now we can't change all code (no autocreate) so we search for a "global" solution if possible to handle the base problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form's `HWND` is getting destroyed when you set the `Position`.  That also destroys all child HWNDs.  The TreeView's `HWND` has not been re-created yet when you read its `Count`, which is why it reports 0.  Calling `TreeView.HandleNeeded` after setting the `Position` forces the TreeView to re-create its `HWND` immediately, which will re-load any TreeNodes that had beencached internally when the TreeView's `HWND` was destroyed (but only if the `TreeView.CreateWndRestores` property is True, which it is by default).

A TreeView stores its child nodes inside of its `HWND`. Reading the `Items.Count` merely asks the `HWND` how many nodes it has, so if there is no `HWND` then the `Count` will be 0.  `TTreeView` does not keep its own list of `TTreeNode` objects, it merely assigns them as user-defined data in the physical nodes themselves.  When nodes are removed from the tree, `TTreeView` frees the associated `TTreeNode` objects.  In the case of `HWND` recreation, `TTreeView` caches the `TTreeNode` data and then re-assigns it back to new nodes when the `HWND` is re-created. But again, it does not keep track of the `TTreeNode` objects.

What `TTreeView` could have done is store the current number of nodes during `HWND` destruction, and then have `Items.Count` return that value if the `HWND` has not been re-created yet. But alas, `TTreeView` does not do that. But you could implement that manually by subclassing `TTreeView` to intercept the `CreateWnd()` and `DestroyWnd()` methods, and then write your own function that returns the actual `Items.Count` when `HandleAllocated` is true and returns your cached value if it is false.

If the Form is visible to the user then its `HWND` (and the `HWND` of its children) will be available, since a control is not visible without an `HWND`, so `Items.Count` will be available if the `TTreeView` is visible to the user. If its `HWND` is ever destroyed while visible, the VCL will re-create the `HWND` immediately so the user does not see a missing control. However, if the Form (or TreeView) is not visible to the user when the `HWND` is destroyed, the `HWND` will not be re-created until it is actually needed when the Form/TreeView is made visible again.

Since you are forcing the `Position` to always be `poDesigned` at the time of Form creation, why not just set the `Position` to `poDesigned` at design-time? Otherwise, you can simply set the `Position` before populating the TreeView instead of afterwards, at least:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, j: integer;
  mn: TTreeNode;
begin
  Position := poDesigned; // <-- here
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    mn := TreeView1.Items.Add(nil, 'M' + IntToStr(i)); // <-- first call to Add() forces HWND recreation if needed
    for j := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      TreeView1.Items.AddChild(mn, 'C' + IntToStr(j));
    end;
  end;
  Beep;
  Caption := IntToStr(TreeView1.Items.Count); // <-- correct value reported
end;
```

This happens in all versions of Delphi. This is simply how things work in the VCL.

On a side note, you should use `Free()` instead of `Release()`. `Release()` is meant to be used only when a Form needs to `Free()` itself, such as in an event handler, by delaying the `Free()` until the Form becomes idle. Since the form is already closed and idle by the time `ShowModal()` exits, it is safe to `Free()` the Form immediately.

Comment: <Since you are forcing the Position to always be poDesigned at the time of Form creation?> That was a demo code. We are using special base form which do things after "FormCreate". For example: if the screen was poScreenCenter, we change it to poDesigned and position to center (because we save and restore the form's position for users). So it's more complex than this demo.
Yesterday my coll. have written a code which an inherited CM_RECREATEWND handler, and what can restore lost handles after the normal handler...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over-reacting. You state:

> The main problem that ReCreateWnd called often by another methods to, so it can cause problems in another sections too, and I cannot put HandleNeeded before all .Count calculation.

But then in comments you say that these other scenarios are:

> CMCtlD3Changed CMSysColorChange BORDERSTYLE SetAxBorderStyle SetBorderIcons Dock SetPosition SetPopupMode set_PopupParent RecreateAsPopup ShowModal SetMainFormOnTaskBar

Indeed these methods will cause window recreation. But why does that matter for you? Do you routinely assign to `MainFormOnTaskBar` and then immediately request the count of items in your tree view? Do you change `Ctl3D` regularly? Are you changing `BorderIcons` dynamically? I very much doubt it.

So I think you need to tackle the immediate problem which relates to the timing of the setting of `Position`. I would deal with that by making sure that `Position` is set before you populate the tree view. Do that by either setting `Position` at design time, or simply before you populate the tree view.

Of course, there may well be other problem related to window creation. You'll need to treat them on a case by case basis. I suspect that you are hoping for some sort of magic switch that just makes this issue disappear. I don't believe that there is one. If you try to read the item count before the handle is created, then you will suffer from this problem. The solution is not to read the item count before the handle is created.